# Multi-threaded Debug DLL vs Multi-threaded Debug App

Tags: c++, delphi, visual-c++

I have a simple C++ DLL project that exports `extern "C"` functions. The library is used by an executable compiled with Delphi. Both binaries are 32-bit. The executable dynamically loads the DLL:

Delphi code:

```pascal
if ( LoadLibrary('Dll1.dll')=0 ) then
begin
  ...
end;
```

The library loads perfectly when the `Multi-threaded Debug` option is selected, and fails if the default value of `Multi-threaded Debug DLL` is selected in `Runtime Library`.

What is the `Runtime Library` option used for, and why does it fail when `Multi-threaded Debug DLL` is selected?

Comment: `Multi-threaded Debug DLL` requires the runtime dll to be installed for the program to run, this should normally be the case as it'll be installed by visual studio

Comment: MS provide a redistributable for the Runtime Support DLLs [Microsoft Visual C++ Redistributable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/windows/latest-supported-vc-redist?view=msvc-170).  Note the the Debug DLLs are not included and you do not have a license to distribute them.  The Debug DLLs are installed when you install C++ Desktop package from the MSVS installer (may be other packages as well).

Comment: When `LoadLibrary()` fails, use `GetLastError()` to find out why. In this case, it likely returns `ERROR_MOD_NOT_FOUND` (126) indicating a dependent DLL is missing